# Right side of touch pad becomes too hot while using Ubuntu

Tags: nvidia, touchpad, overheating, heat, dual-graphics

I have installed Ubuntu 14.10 alongside Windows 8.1. Everything seems correct in Windows but whenever I use Ubuntu, portion near right of touch pad gets too hot. My laptop have 2 GB dedicated Nvidia graphics card which I have disabled from BIOS. I have installed Bumblebee and have selected Intel GPU for usage.
I can't figure out why it gets so hot ?

Comment: also, if you are a firefox user, you may consider installing profile-sync-daemon http://www.webupd8.org/2013/02/keep-your-browser-profiles-in-tmpfs-ram.html

Answer (score 1):

That could be your hard drive. Run the following command to prevent unnecessary spin ups and downs which can lead to undue wear to the drive:

```
sudo hdparm -B 254 /dev/sda
```

Then run the following commands to make the changes permanent:

```
echo "/dev/sda* {" | sudo tee -a /etc/hdparm.conf
echo "  apm = 254" | sudo tee -a /etc/hdparm.conf
echo "  apm_battery = 254" | sudo tee -a /etc/hdparm.conf
echo "}" | sudo tee -a /etc/hdparm.conf
```

---

Also, to make sure all your sensors (temp and otherwise) are detected install lm-sensors, acpi and run sensors-detect:

install:

```
sudo apt-get install acpi acpid acpitool lm-sensors
```

detect:

```
sudo sensors-detect
```

Follow the prompts.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I ran those commands but still it gets hot.

Comment: @Suman one thing you may want to consider is swappiness. If swappiness is set too low or if your swap partition is either too small or non-existent, you can sometimes experience excessive "paging" from a kernel module that can sometimes get stuck in a loop searching the hard drive for available swap space that does not exist. You can run the command `sudo swapon -s` to check the size, availability, currently used ammount, and device or partition of your swapspace.

Comment: @Suman also, you can keep track of hardware temps to get a better idea of where the heat may be coming from by using indicator-sensors. I'll include installation instructions in the answer.'

Comment: sudo swapon -s gave Filename - /dev/sda6 Type - partition Size - 4882428 Priority - -1. My RAM is of 4GB. Previously swappiness was to 60. I changed it to 10. What value will be best ? Does this prevents the heating ? My CPU temperature is 48 C and HDD is 41 C. Are they normal ?

Comment: @Suman that all looks normal. Changing it to 10 may or may not decrease disk activity depending on how you use your computer. Personally I keep it at 60. CPU and HDD look normal but that CPU differs so it's best to look that up to see if it's normal; assuming intel core i, it is good. The only other thing I can think of is maybe turn nvidia on to let it share some of the GPU and/or find out online what is underneath the touchpad there that may be getting hot like the GPU or something.